# Problem in printing Multi-dimentional Array

Tags: php, ajax

I have passed json string through ajax jquery code then i converted it into multi-dimentional associative array. now i am getting problem in printing this multi-dimentional associative array.

## In php file i did this

```
// Retrieve the string, which was sent via the POST parameter "user" 
    $user = $_POST['user'];

// Decode the JSON string and convert it into a PHP associative array.
        $decoded = json_decode($user,true,10);

// var_dump the array so that we can view it's structure.
        var_dump($decoded);
```

## From Ajax request

```
var userStr = JSON.stringify(connections);
$.ajax({
    url: base_url+"ajax/add_google_user",
        type: 'post',
    data: {user: userStr},
    success: function(response){
        appendPre(response);
    }
});
```

I am printing by the var_dump($decoded);
and i require printing with echo how i can?

```
array(5) {
    [0] =>
    array(5) {
        ["resourceName"] =>
        string(27)"people/abc1"
        ["etag"] =>
        string(45)"abc1"
        ["names"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(5) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"618d80f98fe31c72"
                    }
                }
                ["displayName"] =>
                string(12)"Raghav verma"
                ["familyName"] =>
                string(5)"verma"
                ["givenName"] =>
                string(6)"Raghav"
                ["displayNameLastFirst"] =>
                string(13)"verma, Raghav"
            }
        }
        ["emailAddresses"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(2) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"618d80f98fe31c72"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(27)"raghav.verma12345@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["phoneNumbers"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(3) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"618d80f98fe31c72"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(10)"9854251378"
                ["canonicalForm"] =>
                string(13)"+919854251378"
            }
        }
    }
    [1] =>
    array(5) {
        ["resourceName"] =>
        string(27)"people/abc1"
        ["etag"] =>
        string(45)"abc1"
        ["names"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(5) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"69849e8b89f8c048"
                    }
                }
                ["displayName"] =>
                string(13)"Dinesh Chopra"
                ["familyName"] =>
                string(6)"Chopra"
                ["givenName"] =>
                string(6)"Dinesh"
                ["displayNameLastFirst"] =>
                string(14)"Chopra, Dinesh"
            }
        }
        ["emailAddresses"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(2) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"69849e8b89f8c048"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(28)"dinesh.chopra12345@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["phoneNumbers"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(3) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"69849e8b89f8c048"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(10)"9562145678"
                ["canonicalForm"] =>
                string(13)"+919562145678"
            }
        }
    }
    [2] =>
    array(5) {
        ["resourceName"] =>
        string(25)"people/abc1"
        ["etag"] =>
        string(45)"abc1"
        ["names"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(5) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(14)"43f6888c09d0a8"
                    }
                }
                ["displayName"] =>
                string(12)"Rahul Sharma"
                ["familyName"] =>
                string(6)"Sharma"
                ["givenName"] =>
                string(5)"Rahul"
                ["displayNameLastFirst"] =>
                string(13)"Sharma, Rahul"
            }
        }
        ["emailAddresses"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(2) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(14)"43f6888c09d0a8"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(28)"rahul.sharma123456@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["phoneNumbers"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(3) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(14)"43f6888c09d0a8"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(11)"97854 63214"
                ["canonicalForm"] =>
                string(13)"+919785463214"
            }
        }
    }
    [3] =>
    array(5) {
        ["resourceName"] =>
        string(27)"people/abc1"
        ["etag"] =>
        string(45)"abc1"
        ["names"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(5) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"1bdbb17e08cff0b6"
                    }
                }
                ["displayName"] =>
                string(11)"Tarun Mehta"
                ["familyName"] =>
                string(5)"Mehta"
                ["givenName"] =>
                string(5)"Tarun"
                ["displayNameLastFirst"] =>
                string(12)"Mehta, Tarun"
            }
        }
        ["emailAddresses"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(2) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"1bdbb17e08cff0b6"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(27)"tarun.mehta123456@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["phoneNumbers"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(3) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(16)"1bdbb17e08cff0b6"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(11)"92635 47815"
                ["canonicalForm"] =>
                string(13)"+919263547815"
            }
        }
    }
    [4] =>
    array(4) {
        ["resourceName"] =>
        string(26)"people/abc1"
        ["etag"] =>
        string(45)"abc1"
        ["names"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(4) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(15)"8e3b6280a6e5da2"
                    }
                }
                ["displayName"] =>
                string(26)"aniltulipacademy@gmail.com"
                ["givenName"] =>
                string(26)"aniltulipacademy@gmail.com"
                ["displayNameLastFirst"] =>
                string(26)"aniltulipacademy@gmail.com"
            }
        }
        ["emailAddresses"] =>
        array(1) {
            [0] =>
            array(2) {
                ["metadata"] =>
                array(2) {
                    ["primary"] =>
                    bool(true)
                    ["source"] =>
                    array(2) {
                        ["type"] =>
                        string(7)"CONTACT"
                        ["id"] =>
                        string(15)"8e3b6280a6e5da2"
                    }
                }
                ["value"] =>
                string(26)"aniltulipacademy@gmail.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `print_r`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to print a multidimensional array, you can use as many iterative statement like `for` you need, to dig and print all level of your array using an `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.var-export.php) if you pass true as a second parameters you can put the content into a var.

```
$a = var_export([ 1 => 2 ], true);

echo $a;
```

If you want to use var_dumps for some obscure reasons you can use buffers to capture the output:

```
ob_start();
var_dump([ "a" => "1" ]);
$a = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $a;
```